# Textblock's content is not centered

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, alignment, block

[View of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhY6V.png)

Hi sof, recently i made a resource dictionary. I streched my button to the grid's height and at the resource dictionary in the textblock of button's content presenter section, i changed the horizontal and vertical content alignment to center like below;

```
<Style x:Key="RButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <TextBlock x:Name="b" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
                   <ContentPresenter 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
              ...
```

and yes, it worked. But not perfectly. See the link above and have a look to what i'm saying. Where can i get some detailed info about it, or can you help me about this?

*I did not changed anything on textblock's content section except for this. If you want the full code of my resource dictionary i may post it for you.*

Comment: Sorry but no, vertical or horizontal alignment in contentpresenter already equals to that (i guess). There is no vertical/horizontal content alignment inside the contentpresenter. I checked the website so i wont do duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for not mention. It is in the setter's property value section. So there is no Horizontal/VerticalContentAlignment exists in TextBlock.

Comment: http://puu.sh/rcdVE/89f346f002.png
i guess this snapshot should explain everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since you're using `TextBlock` directly, you need just set the [TextAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) property to "Center" to get your centered text as `HorizontalContentAlignment` property is not present in `TextBlock`.

So;

```
<TextBlock x:Name="b" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

However, unless I'm mistaken, you need a parent panel for your control template as it should error currently if `Content` of `Button` is filled since there's more than one child in the object tree. So you'll also want to add something to house the children like a simple `Grid` or `StackPanel` etc.

Like;

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
   <Grid>
      <TextBlock x:Name="b" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 TextAlignment="Center"/>
      <ContentPresenter 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If you wanted to use the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property of `Button` you need to include it in your template somewhere.

Like for example;

```
<TextBlock x:Name="b" 
           HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Hope this helps, cheers!